# Django Setting class of <ul> instead of <input> with CheckboxSelectMultiple widget

Tags: django, django-forms

I can set the class of a widget with a line like

```
self.widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'myclass'})
```

but this applies `myclass` to all of the `<li>` elements, e.g.,

```
<ul>
    <label><li><input type="checkbox" class="myclass">1</li></label>
    <label><li><input type="checkbox" class="myclass">2</li></label>
    <label><li><input type="checkbox" class="myclass">3</li></label>
</ul>
```

How can I apply a class to only the `<ul>` element?

Comment: I think I found my answer: You can't.

Looking in [django/forms/widgets.py][1], the render method appears to generate its output by starting with `output = [u'<ul>']` and appending an option for every element in the given queryset `output.append(u'<li><label%s>%s %s</label></li>' % (label_for, rendered_cb, option_label))`.  So the `<ul>` tag is hard-coded and my only option is to create a custom widget. 


  [1]: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/widgets.py

Comment: Depending on hard-coded implementation details can and will bite you in the future. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default you cannot set the attribute on the UL tag.  The "easy" thing to do is subclass the CheckboxSelectMultiple to do what you want.  Two approaches are:

Construct a custom version of the CheckboxSelectMultiple with a "ulattrs" argument.

```
class MyCheckboxSelectMultiple(CheckboxSelectMultiple):
    def render(self, name, value, ulattrs=None, attrs=None, choices=()):
        if value is None: value = []
        has_id = attrs and 'id' in attrs
        final_attrs = self.build_attrs(attrs, name=name)
        output = [u'<ul class="%s">' % ulattrs.get('class')]
        # Normalize to strings
        str_values = set([force_unicode(v) for v in value])
        for i, (option_value, option_label) in enumerate(chain(self.choices, choices)):
            # If an ID attribute was given, add a numeric index as a suffix,
            # so that the checkboxes don't all have the same ID attribute.
            if has_id:
                final_attrs = dict(final_attrs, id='%s_%s' % (attrs['id'], i))
                label_for = u' for="%s"' % final_attrs['id']
            else:
                label_for = ''

            cb = CheckboxInput(final_attrs, check_test=lambda value: value in str_values)
            option_value = force_unicode(option_value)
            rendered_cb = cb.render(name, option_value)
            option_label = conditional_escape(force_unicode(option_label))
            output.append(u'<li><label%s>%s %s</label></li>' % (label_for, rendered_cb, option_label))
        output.append(u'</ul>')
        return mark_safe(u'\n'.join(output))
```

or, you could do something a little more hacky...

```
class MyCheckboxSelectMultiple(CheckboxSelectMultiple):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, choices=()):
        html = super(MyCheckboxSelectMultiple, self).render(name, value, attrs, choices)

        return mark_safe(html.replace('<ul>', '<ul class="foobar">'))
```

Comment: The hacky solution is perfect as far as I can tell. Am I failing to see some potential pitfall?

Comment: Shouldn't be any pitfall.  As a small caveat I coded the example code from memory, it's not been run anywhere.

Comment: I tried your hacky solution to implement in my application but i am getting this error "Could not import setting.views.location. View does not exist in module setting.views." I raised a question in SO also please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18662626/how-to-produce-span-instead-of-li-tag you definite give me solution i believe.I don't have enough reputation to award this question for bounty else i do that so diferent answer i will get Thanks

Comment: The hacky solution doesn't work from Django 1.6 on, the `<ul>` now looks like `<ul id="id_field_name">`

Comment: such 'easy'  DOM changes are hell in Django

Answer (score 0):

Building on Koblas, another somewhat more general approach is:

```
class CheckboxSelectMultipleULAttrs(forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple):
    """
    Class to allow setting attributes on containing ul in a CheckboxSelectMultiple
    """
    def __init__(self, ulattrs=None, attrs=None, choices=()):
        self.ulattrs = ulattrs
        super(CheckboxSelectMultipleULAttrs, self).__init__(attrs, choices)
        return

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, choices=()):
        html = super(CheckboxSelectMultipleULAttrs, self).render(name, value, attrs, choices)
        if not self.ulattrs:
            return html
        return mark_safe(html.replace('<ul>', '<ul ' + self.ulattrs + '>'))
```

Comment: Just have the replace be `replace('<ul', '<ul '.....` (i.e. omit the closing > tag) for 1.6.