# how to produce <span> instead of <li> tag

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

forms.py

```
class ZergitForm(forms.Form):

    zerg_selection = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),required=False)
```

views.py

```
def feeds(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        zergform = ZergitForm(request.POST)
        """"""""
        some other logic comes here
        """"""""
    selection = ZergitForm(zerg_id)
    return render(request, 'feed_list.html',{'zerg_selection':zerg_selection})
```

feed_list.html

```
{% for feed in selection.zerg_selection %}
<span class="checkbox_select">{{ feed }}</span>
{% endfor %}
```

Problem is it is rendering as a list of check boxes in a `<li>` tag.But what i required is the input field with check box inside the `<span>` tag.How to implement it in my application.

Answer (score 0):

There is no clean solution for that, either you define your own CheckboxSelectMultiple widget with overridden render method (which imho, is way to much overhead):

https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.5.2/django/forms/widgets.py#L754

or you use small hack (in that case you replace `<li>` and `</li>` etc):

[Django Setting class of <ul> instead of <input> with CheckboxSelectMultiple widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852609/django-setting-class-of-ul-instead-of-input-with-checkboxselectmultiple-widg)

or you customize template output:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15441506/1566605